# How do I store my numbers into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

In my code, I am trying to generate 5 numbers. If any of the numbers equal to 4, then I want to store that 4 into an array. Currently I'm having trouble and my code will not store the 4 into the array.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int total = 0, randInt;

        Console.WriteLine("The computer is now rolling their dice...");
        int[] fours = new int[total];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            randInt = rand.Next(10);
            Console.WriteLine("The computer rolls a {0:F0}", randInt);
            if (randInt == 4)
            {
                total +=fours[i]; //Here I am trying to store the 4 into the array of 'fours'.

            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine(total); //This currently prints to 0, regardless of any 4's the random number generator has generated. I want this to print out how many 4's I have rolled.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
total +=fours[i]
```

Will attempt to increment `total` with the `int` found at index `i` of your array (which will currently be 0, because int defaults to 0).

This:

```
fours[i] = 4;
```

Is how you assign 4 to the ith index in your array.

Read about how the [assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) works in C#

> The = operator is called the simple assignment operator. It **assigns the value of the right operand** to the variable, property, or indexer element given by **the left operand.**

Comment: If I assign the array to 4, how do I then write this out?

I'm currently writing out total at the end, and still amounts to 0.

Comment: @Daniel What do you wish to print? The total sum of the arrays values?

Comment: A simple `Console.WriteLine(fours.Sum());` will do then